# Import data to PostGIS DB via QGIS DB Manager is very slow

Tags: qgis, postgis, import, dbmanager

I am wondering why importing a large vectorlayer (700.000 Polygons) with ogr2ogr tool takes only a few seconds and via QGIS DB Manager more than 1,5 hours.

Why is DB Manager so slow with large layers? With small layers (e.g. a few hundred objects) DB Manager works fine.

Comment: it might be using multiple transactions - you'd need to check the code to be sure.

Comment: @Ian: Thanks for your answer. Where can I check the code?

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/db_manager

Answer (score 4):

ogr2ogr, that can be accessed also via the Processing Toolbox 'Export to PostgreSQL' can use COPY faster instruction, instead of single INSERT for each records.

Comment: correct sql copy is much faster - insert will commit each entry before the next feature.